# Create and append pandas dummy variables with pipe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a Pandas pipeline that creates dummy variables and append the column to the existing dataframe.
Unfortunately I can't get the appended columns to stick when the pipeline is finished.

Example:

```
def function(df):
    pass

def create_dummy(df):
    a = pd.get_dummy(df['col'])
    b = df.append(a)
    return b

def mah_pipe(df):
    (df.pipe(function)
     .pipe(create_dummy)
     .pipe(print)
    return df

print(mah_pipe(df))
```

First - I have no idea if this is good practice.
What's weird is that the `.pipe(print)` prints the dataframe with appended columns. Yay.

But the statement `print(mah_pipe(df))` does not. I though they would behave the same way.
I have tried to read the documentation about `pd.pipe` but I couldn't figure it out.

Hoping someone could help shed some light on what's going on.

Comment: because your `create_dummy` function doesn't modify `df` but creates a new data frame, neither `mah_pipe`...

Comment: OMG. That was an easy fix. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have attempted to correct your pipelines. Your `create_dummy`  works. `pipe` returns a DataFrame or whatever is returned by the function used  and pass forward. The issue is with `print` as a function. `print` return `None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `print` in Python returns `None`. Since you are not making a copy of `df` on your pipes, your `df` dies after `print`.

### pipes in Pandas

Unless used as last pipe, in Pandas, we except `(df) -> [pipe] -> (df_1)-> [pipe2] ->(df_2)-> [pipeN] -> df_N` By having print as last pipe, the output is `None`.

#### Solution

```py
...
def start_pipe(dataf):
    # allows make a copy to avoid modifying original 
    dataf = dataf.copy()

def create_dummies(dataf, column_name):
    dummies = pd.get_dummies(dataf[column_name])
    dataf[dummies.columns] = dummies

    return dataf

def print_dataf(dataf, n_rows=5):
    print(dataf.head(n_rows))

    return dataf # this is important 

# usage

...
dt = (df
           .pipe(start_pipe)
           .pipe(create_dummies, column_name='a')
           .pipe(print_dataf, n_rows=10)
)
```

```py
def mah_pipe(df):
     df = (df
           .pipe(start_pipe)
           .pipe(create_dummies, column_name='a')
           .pipe(print_dataf, n_rows=10)
    )
    return df

print(mah_pipe(df))
```

Comment: See https://calmcode.io/pandas-pipe/introduction.html for beautiful introduction to how to use pipes